# iodine and bind on same server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, forwarding

I have recently setup a server running ubuntu server 12.04. I bought a domain, example.com, and have registered nameservers ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com. Both point towards my server running bind at 12.345.678.90. Everything works great. I have successfully configured bind, and can access my domain. I want to also experiment with iodine. Because I am just doing all of this out of curiosity and to learn, I don't have the resources to have multiple servers with multiple ips. I know that I have to forward the iodine tunnel through another port in bind, but I'm not entirely sure how. Right now I have iodine.example.com as an NS record pointing to tunnel.example.com. As of now, I have tunnel.example.com pointing to a friends server running iodine. Everything works. Since I won't always have access to the second server, how do I configure iodine to work behind bind on the same server?

Answer (score 2):

Set up BIND to listen on another port (eg. `5353`), and in `iodine` use the `-b 5353` option

from `man iodine`:

```
   -b dnsport
          If this port is specified, all incoming requests not inside  the
          tunnel domain will be forwarded to this port on localhost, to be
          handled by a real dns.  Note: The forwarding is not fully trans‐
          parent, and not advised for use in production environments.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in different ways:
http://dev.kryo.se/iodine/wiki/TipsAndTricks